# Flutter _ClientSocketException (Connection timed out)

Tags: node.js, flutter, http

**config.dart**

```
class Config {
  static const String appName = 'Shopping app';
  static const String apiURL = '192.168.8.101:4000';
  static const String loginAPI = '/users/login';
  static const String registerAPI = '/users/register';
  static const String userProfileAPI = '/users/user-Profile';
}
```

**api_services.dart**

```
class APIService {
  static var client = http.Client();

  static Future<bool> login(LoginRequestModel model) async {
    Map<String, String> requestHeaders = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    };

    var url = Uri.http(Config.apiURL, Config.loginAPI);

    var response = await client.post(
      url,
      headers: requestHeaders,
      body: jsonEncode(model.toJson()),
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      await SharedService.setLoginDetails(loginResponseJson(response.body));
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  static Future<RegisterResponseModel> register(
      RegisterRequestModel model) async {
    Map<String, String> requestHeaders = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    };

    var url = Uri.http(Config.apiURL, Config.registerAPI);

    var response = await client.post(
      url,
      headers: requestHeaders,
      body: jsonEncode(model.toJson()),
    );

    return registerResponseJson(response.body);
  }
}
```

**login.dart**

```
FormHelper.submitButton(
  'Login',
  btnColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 25, 19, 83),
  borderColor: Colors.white,
  borderRadius: 10,
  () {
    print('Login');
  
    if (validateAndSave()) {
      setState(() {
        isApiCallProcess = true;
      });
    
      LoginRequestModel model = LoginRequestModel(
        username: username!,
        password: password!,
      );

      APIService.login(model).then(
        (response) {
          setState(() {
            isApiCallProcess = false;
          });

        if (response) {
          Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
              homeRoute, (route) => false);
        } else {
          FormHelper.showSimpleAlertDialog(
            context,
            Config.appName,
            'Invalid credentials',
            'OK',
            () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            );
          }
        },
      );
    }
  },
),
```

I'm trying to login with NodeJS.

But when I clicked log in button it throws me an exception saying

**`_ClientSocketException (Connection timed out`**

My PC IP address is showing **192.168.8.100** and when I `netstat -a` in **cmd** it showing listening **192.168.8.100:139**.

I'm using my mobile phone as emulator for debugging.

IP address of mobile phone is **192.168.8.101**

What's wrong with my code???

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple, hope you got it.

Just make this change `static const String apiURL = '192.168.8.100:4000';` to reflect your PC's ip which is serving the api (probably port 4000, should not be 139 since ports < 1024 are reserved ['well-known ports'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers#Well-known_ports))

Another point:
You should always handle exceptions so your app does not crash. In this case, if your api becomes unreachable.

```
try {
 var response = await client.post(
   url,
   headers: requestHeaders,
   body: jsonEncode(model.toJson()),
 );

 if (response.statusCode == 200) {
   await SharedService.setLoginDetails(loginResponseJson(response.body));
   return true;
 } else {
   return false;
 } 
} on SocketException { 
// TODO: handle connection problem
} catch (e) {
// TODO: handle all other exceptions just in case
}
```